# oci_bind_by_name - not all variables bound error

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I want to bind the variables in a query like this:

```
SELECT people.name, conf.id
FROM people, conf
WHERE people.confid=conf.id AND people.name LIKE :c1 AND conf.name LIKE :c2
```

The binding (I try to use a very simple expression):

```
$tmp = '%';
$tmp2= '%';

oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':c1', $tmp);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':c2', $tmp2);
```

The Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-01008: not all variables bound in ....php on line 162

If I generate the query on the fly, with: {$tmp} instead of :c1, it works.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does `$statement` come from?

Comment: '$statement = oci_parse($connection, $query);' where query is the query above.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and replace your comments about what code looks like (in which I see nothing wrong) with the actual code. Sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: I solved the problem:

I didn't call the `oci_free_statement()` method. That's a little weird, because on my other page in the same database connection, the binding worked fine, without calling the free method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

I didn't call the oci_free_statement() method. That's a little weird, because on my other page in the same database connection, the binding worked fine, without calling the free method...